# Computing filter(b,a,x,zi) using FFTs

Tags: python, matlab, filter, signal-processing, octave

I would like to try to compute `y=filter(b,a,x,zi)` and `dy[i]/dx[j]` using FFTs rather than in the time domain for possible speedup in a GPU implementation.

I am not sure it's possible, particularly when `zi` is non-zero. I looked through how `scipy.signal.lfilter` in scipy and `filter` in octave are implemented. They are both done directly in the time domain, with scipy using direct form 2 and octave direct form 1 (from looking through code in `DLD-FUNCTIONS/filter.cc`). I haven't seen anywhere an FFT implementation analogous to `fftfilt` for FIR filters in MATLAB (i.e. a = [1.]).

I tried doing `y = ifft(fft(b) / fft(a) * fft(x))` but this seems to be conceptually wrong. Also, I am not sure how to handle the initial transient `zi`. Any references, pointer to existing implementation, would be appreciated.

Example code,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create an IRR lowpass filter
N = 5
b, a = sg.butter(N, .4)
MN = max(len(a), len(b))

# create a random signal to be filtered
T = 100
P = T + MN - 1
x = np.random.randn(T)
zi = np.zeros(MN-1)

# time domain filter
ylf, zo = sg.lfilter(b, a, x, zi=zi)

# frequency domain filter
af = sg.fft(a, P)
bf = sg.fft(b, P)
xf = sg.fft(x, P)
yfft = np.real(sg.ifft(bf/af * xf))[:T]

# error
print np.linalg.norm(yfft - ylf)

# plot, note error is larger at beginning and with larger N
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(ylf)
plt.plot(yfft)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the error in your existing implementation by replacing `P = T + MN - 1` with `P = T + 2*MN - 1`.  This is purely intuitive, but it seems to me that the division of `bf` and `af` will require `2*MN` terms, due to wraparound.

C.S. Burrus has a pretty terse writeup of how to regard filtering, whether FIR or IIR, in a block oriented way, [here](http://cnx.org/content/m16339/latest/).  I haven't read it in detail, but I think it gives you the equations you need to implement IIR filtering by convolution, including intermediate states.

Comment: It seems error decreases as you increase padding but it doesn't get eliminated. That's why I thought my FFT attempt was conceptually flawed. Thanks for the Burrus reference. At the moment, I don't have to implement a block version of filter as T is small.

Comment: If T is small, then I assume your IIR filter's impulse response is also short.  I suggest windowing the impulse response, giving up a bit of sharpness in the frequency response, and treating it as an FIR.  This is at least conceptually guaranteed to be sound.  Your approach feels right, but I'm not totally convinced...

Comment: That sounds like a good idea if I was free to design the filter. In this case, I was given the task of computing filter(b,a,x,zi) exactly. I am not allowed to convert the filter to an FIR.

Comment: Multiplying FFTs does circular convolution.  Thus FFT filtering is only exact if both T and the impulse response of the filter are finite, and the FFT size is larger than the sum of both.  Otherwise you will get wrap-around "error".

Comment: @hotpaw2, I guess the conclusion is that you can't naively use FFTs for IIR filters. I need to learn more signal processing!

Comment: @Paul : FFTs are used for approximating IIR filters.  You chop off (window) the "infinite" portion of the IIR past the point where the effects of the filter drop below your application's noise floor, and sometimes 90+dB will do even for some "exact" filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I've forgotten what little I knew about FFTs but you could take a look at sedit.py and frequency.py at http://jc.unternet.net/src/ and see if anything there would help.

Comment: Thanks. It seems this code computes power spectra of sound signals. I wasn't able to find where the IRR filtering via FFT takes place.

Answer (score 1):

Try `scipy.signal.lfiltic(b, a, y, x=None)` to obtain the initial conditions.

Doc text for `lfiltic`:

```
Given a linear filter (b,a) and initial conditions on the output y
and the input x, return the inital conditions on the state vector zi
which is used by lfilter to generate the output given the input.

If M=len(b)-1 and N=len(a)-1.  Then, the initial conditions are given
in the vectors x and y as

x = {x[-1],x[-2],...,x[-M]}
y = {y[-1],y[-2],...,y[-N]}

If x is not given, its inital conditions are assumed zero.
If either vector is too short, then zeros are added
  to achieve the proper length.

The output vector zi contains

zi = {z_0[-1], z_1[-1], ..., z_K-1[-1]}  where K=max(M,N).
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Given zi, how would you then compute y[0:T] with FFTs (as is done, for example, in scipy.signal.fftconvolve)? That is my question.